# SpringMVC and Java Servlet code in the same class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

Can you have `Spring Controller/MVC` and the traditional `Java Servlet code (doPost)` executed through  the same servlet? We have a legacy webapp that implements a mix of Spring MVC on certain areas and Java Servlet code to support other areas. Now due to the below vulnerability identified, we are trying to replace `Spring multipart file` feature with `Apache Commons FileUpload`.

[Spring Multipart/form-data vulnerability](https://spring.io/security/cve-2022-22970)

Is there a way to add the doPost() handler to exclusively handle the fileUpload feature in a Spring Controller class? (implemented using @Controller).

In other words, use `Spring Controller` for rest of the functionalities and `doPost()` just for the file upload feature in the same servlet?

**Spring Controller Code:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        boolean updated = false;
        String uploadDir = "/WEB-INF/";
        String realPath = request.getServletContext()
                .getRealPath(uploadDir);

        File transferFile = new File(
                realPath + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        file.transferTo(transferFile);
        String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(
                Paths.get(realPath + file.getOriginalFilename())));
        logger.debug(contents);

        ..........
            more code
            
                updated = true;
                ((ModelMap) model).addAttribute("errors", ""); //reset any previous errors
        
        } else {//if invalid file, show error msg
            String error = MessageBoxUtil.getErrorMessageBox(
                    "Invalid Key Found. Please try again.");
            ((ModelMap) model).addAttribute("errors", error);

        }
        
        model.put("updated", updated);

        return mv;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Exception ocurred: " +e);
        //e.printStackTrace();
        new TemplateManager(request).doError(e, request, response);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Replace the above with the code below:**

```
    /* Apache Commons File Upload */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     
      try {

    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setRepository(new File("C:\\temp\\"));
        ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List<FileItem> fileItems = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
    for(FileItem fileItem : fileItems) {
          if(!fileItem.isFormField()) {   
            File file = new File(fileItem.getName());  
            File fNew= new File("C:\\upload\\"  + file.getName());
            fileItem.write(fNew);
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        String fileUploadError = "Problem with Apache Commons File Upload.";
        System.out.println(fileUploadError);
      } 
    }
```

JSp Code:

```
     <form name="uploadFile" method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br />     
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="importkey" value="Import Key"/>
</form>
```

Comment: "_Users of affected versions should apply the following mitigation: 5.3.x users should upgrade to 5.3.20; 5.2.x users should upgrade to 5.2.22. No other steps are necessary._"

Comment: @jaco0646 - Its a legacy app and hence upgrading to latest Spring is a huge effort and we have time constraints to deliver a temporary fix to the clients during the interim. Hence looking for alternative options. We are on Spring 4.x (un supported version)